# Alien frontiers: how many fields in a single territory?

Tags: alien-frontiers

While playing Alien frontiers, if a field is already placed on a territory, am I allowed to place another field on the same territory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can have multiple fields in the same territory.**

The [rules](http://www.gamesalute.com/sites/default/files/AlienFrontiers-rules_0.pdf) don't explicitly address this (Fields can be found on page 12). However, there is a [thread on Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/706941/multiple-fields-same-territory) where this question is asked, and multiple users answer that it is "perfectly legal," with no dissenting opinions.

Between the lack of explicit ruling in the rulebook, and the validation from other users, it appears that you are fine to place or move fields into the same territory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rules found at this pdf link, on page 12 (which addresses fields) it says:

> The Repulsor Field prevents colonies from
>   being added to or removed from the territory
>   on which it is located. **The Repulsor Field does
>   not prevent its own movement or removal, *nor
>   does it prevent the movement or removal of any
>   other field generator that is also on that territory*.**
>   The first player to discard a Gravity Manipulator
>   card will place the Repulsor Field counter on a
>   territory of their choice. Any subsequent player
>   who discards a Gravity Manipulator card will
>   move the counter to another territory.

This makes it clear that the rules *do* allow for the Repulsor Field to be in the same territory as another. Without an explicit statement otherwise, I can't see why the other fields wouldn't be allowed in the same territory without the Repulsor Field.